# Status bar text instead of an icon

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

How can you put text in the status bar and get it to stay there when the window is not expanded? Similar to using text instead of an icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an icon that is comprised of words. Since the [UI guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#statusbarstructure) call for a 25x25 pixel icon, those words will need to be very tiny.

There is no other option for introducing persistent text into the status bar from the SDK.